# What are the potential hazards of an object removing itself from a list it is in?

Tags: c#

For instance, if I have an class:

```
public class StuffHolder
{

    List<Stuff> myList;

    public StuffHolder()
    {
        myList = newList<Stuff>();
        myList.Add(new Stuff(myList));
        myList[0].stuffHappens();
    }

}
```

and a Stuff Object:

```
public class Stuff
{
    List<Stuff> myList;

    public Stuff(List<Stuff> myList)
    {
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    public void stuffHappens()
    {
        myList.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

What are the disadvantages of calling stuffHappens() rather than having stuff pass the information that it should be removed to the StuffHolder class and having the StuffHolder class remove that specific Stuff?

Comment: Potential hazard from what point of view? List only holds references to objects, and removing one reference from a list wouldn't break anything

Comment: There's the hazard that it's not the right thing to do and will break things, except it's impossible to tell from just this example. One thing that comes to mind that you shouldn't remove stuff from a list that's currently being iterated, and your code would make this harder to notice.

Comment: Why do you want to do something like this when it is clearly showing  you that it might be Hazardous

Comment: My question is why is it "not the right thing to do" and why is it "clearly hazardous." I tried to keep it as generic as possible intentionally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a hazard if stuffHappens() ever occurs in more than one thread at a time, as the `List<T>` collection is not thread-safe.

The bigger hazard is the confusion of responsibility, as it probably shouldn't be the job of Stuff to know about it being stored in a collection.  This kind of design 'fuzziness' causes steadily increasing confusion as systems grow and evolve.

Answer (score 0):

It will certainly work (i.e. the Stuff object will be removed from the list).

The question is why you have a StuffHolder in the first place. Usually when you wrap a collection like that you are doing it to maintain some invariants or cache some data. Using the list like this means you could violate the invariant.

Essentially the issue is that StuffHolder has no idea that an object has been removed from it's list. It's up to you whether that is a problem for your particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible from the code perspective, so it's ok. The answer depends on what you are modeling, the design you have made. May be some scenarios where that solution is not a good one and some scenarios where it is. If you want, you can share what are you trying to achieve and we can discuss then.

Hope it helps.